# How will you answer Inverse trigonometric equation if you haven't memorize the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry

The video tutorials always have the unit circle written and you are not allowed to do that during quizzes... Is there a way for me to answer inverse trigonometric equations without the need to memorize the unit circle? I still have not memorize it

Comment: http://www.moomoomath.com/Easy-way-Learn-Unit-Circle.html

Comment: You need to memorize these values. There's no way around it. Everybody used to memorize dozens of phone numbers of their friends and family, and it was not just people with good memories. This is easier than that. I recommend you try it instead of worrying about it.

Comment: You can get all of it from the 45-45-90 triangle and the 30-60-90 triangle. The values for the former can be gotten from the Pythagorean theorem; the values for the latter can be gotten from the fact that it's half of an equilateral triangle (as well as the Pythagorean theorem).

Comment: Also, interesting fact: The values of $\sin0$, $\sin30^\circ$, $\sin45^\circ$, $\sin60^\circ$, and $\sin90^\circ$ are $\frac{\sqrt0}2$, $\frac{\sqrt1}2$, $\frac{\sqrt2}2$, $\frac{\sqrt3}2$, and $\frac{\sqrt4}2$, respectively. For cosine it's the same but in the opposite order.

Answer (score 1):

As per Akiva Weinberger columbus' comment, use triangles to determine the values.
[image]